# Command Update-Database -Context "IdentityDbContext" Doesn't Create Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a previous created project from "ASP.NET Core: Security" LinkedIn Learn Course (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap1TSQ4qoVyxgrImtb6ZFwZXQGW2BA) and in this project already exists the Migrations [Migrations Folder Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OVCF.png) folder that represents the objects that will be create in data base when executed the command Update-Database -Context "IdentityDbContext". The problem Is  that when I execute the command in Package Manager Console I have no return and the data base is not created.

I tried to update the project to .net 2.2. I also tried with another database.

The entire project is here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap1TSQ4qoVyxgrImtb6ZFwZXQGW2BA

I have no error or feedback from visual studio when the command is executed. 
[image: No return from command's execution image]

Comment: Try again without the `""`

Comment: It works correctly with your uploaded project. Are you able to build your project? Try to run `nuget restore` before run this command. Try to run `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: @TaoZhou , thank you very much! Your tip resolved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran [dotnet --list-sdks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L4HP.png) and realized that I didn't have .NET Core SDK 1.1 installed in my machine.

I Installed it and ran [Update-Database -Context "IdentityDbContext"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HMsO.png) again with success.